# Store rows of resultset in array of strings

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I want to count the numbers of entries in resultset and then store these values in an array and pass this array to create a graph.

```
     ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( "SELECT distinct "+jTextField.getText()+" as 
     call from tablename"); // this statement will select the unique entries in a 
                              particular column provided by jtextfield

     int count=0;

     while(rs.next())
       { ++count; } // This will count the number of entries in the result set.
```

Now I want to store the values of result set in an array of string. I used the following code

```
    String[] row = new String[count];
    while(rs.next())
     {
       for (int i=0; i <columnCount ; i++)
        {
          row[i] = rs.getString(i + 1);
        }
     }
```

Error : Invalid Descriptor Index.
Please suggest how to copy the result of resultset in array.

For example if I enter priority in jTextField , the result set will contain
priority1
priority2
priority3

Comment: Start with `PreparedStatement` , use a `List` and populate it while you iterate the `ResultSet`.

Comment: @TheNewIdiot even with a `PreparedStatement`, you can't dynamically set the name of the column to retrieve =\

Comment: Moreover , how many columns you have in that Select statement , looks like you are trying to access column index which doesn't exist.

Comment: In second while loop rs.next() don't get any values

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your first `while` loop you read all the entries in the `ResultSet`, so when executing the second `while` loop there's nothing else to read. Also, the index of `ResultSet#getXxx` starts at 1, not at 0. Also, since you don't know the amount of rows that you will read, it will be better using a `List` backed by `ArrayList` instead.

Considering these, your code should look like:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( "SELECT distinct "+jTextField.getText()+
    " as call from tablename");
List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
while(rs.next()) {
    results.add(rs.getString(1));
}
```

Based in your comment, I extended the sample:

```
public List<String> yourRandomQuery(String columnName) {
    Connection con = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        String baseQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT %s AS call FROM tablename";
        con = ...; //retrieve your connection
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(String.format(baseQuery, columnName));
        while(rs.next()) {
            results.add(rs.getString(1));
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        //handle your exception
        e.printStacktrace(System.out);
    } finally {
        closeResource(rs);
        closeResource(con);
    }
    return results;
}

//both Connection and ResultSet interfaces extends from AutoCloseable interface
public void closeResource(AutoCloseable ac) {
    try {
        if (ac != null) {
            ac.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //handle this exception as well...
    }
}

public void someMethod() {
    //retrieve the results from database
    List<String> results = yourRandomQuery(jTextField.getText());
    //consume the results as you wish
    //basic example: printing them in the console
    for(String result : results) {
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: how to use this result to get each value individually.

Comment: @pallavi you're getting each result individually but adding them in a `List<String>` so you could consume each value by reading it from the `List`. What's your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( "SELECT distinct "+jTextField.getText()+" as
            call from tablename");      
    List<String> list=new ArrayList<>();

    while(rs.next())
    {
       list.add(rs.getString(1));


    }
```

Comment: Note that `getString` receives the index of the column to get, not the number of the row to get, so if your query results in a single column, this will break when using `rs.getString(2)`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create a `HashSet<String>` and write into that. Note that `HashSet` is unordered, just like your query. By using a collection that is of arbitrary size you don't need to determine the require dsize in advance.

Comment: The copy of the result would be a single column

Comment: Note I've changed my answer *dramatically* since your comment :-)